# Parse an xml once for use across many activities

Tags: android, parsing, android-activity, sax

I'm working with SaxParser to parse an xml. The problem is, I have a few screens or activities coded. At the moment, every time I transition to the new activity from a button press for example, the new activity needs to then parse the xml all over again, so it can populate the screen with the specific content.

Is there a way in which I only parse the xml once through the life of the program?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just parse it once and store what you want to remember in variables.

More completely, you would probably create a class (or classes) classes that represent with properties the same information that is in the xml document.  A constructor of the class would take the xml as an argument, parse it, and populate the properties.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sometime earliear I faced the similar problem the problem is that android only allow some of generic datatypes to be sent across activities and if your datatype is not generic then the only solution that I came across it make it public and static

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want a global data to be shared across activities. Then either you can make it static or just create a singleton class and use it across activities. In this singleton class you can store parsed data.

In android there is facility for extending Application class and declaring it manifest file.
So, in any activity you can do getApplication() and access the single instance of that class.
Again this will be similar to Singleton class.

Answer (score 0):

The Application Framework FAQ has a discussion about how to [share data structures across activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/framework.html#3). Since each activity usually has its own process, it isn't quite as simple as declaring a singleton object.